# How to get a custom running foot in the scrbook class with scrlayer-scrpage package?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm working on a book, in whose design I have empty header and all information is on foot. I'm using the `scrbook` class for this work.

So, on the outside part of the foot I have the page numbers, while on the left  page (verso) I have the title of the book, and on the right (recto) I have the name of the chapter in which I am.

I think I could do this using the `scrlayer-scrpage` package, but I'm confused with several issues.

I know I can use `\ofoot{\pagemark}` to place the page numbers in position, but if I use `\cfoot` I can't differentiate the odd page content from the even page.

I have reviewed several similar questions here and I am confused about the use of options in the case of `\ofoot`, by example. I think I understand the use of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` but not `\headmark`. I'm also not clear when it is convenient to use `\clearpairofpagestyles`.

My MWE could be something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\automark{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles 
\ofoot{\pagemark} 
\lcfoot{Book Title}
\rcfoot{\sectionmark} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\chapter{First chapter} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A section} 
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another} 
\lipsum[11-15] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the sections in the footer at all? You don't mention them.

Comment: Actually no, simply the chapter in the footer, the section isn't necessary, in fact few chapters hasn't sections.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

`\clearpairofpagestyles` removes the predefined content of both pagestyle `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. There are also the commands `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles` and `\clearplainofpairofpagestyles` to clean `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` respectively.

Note that with package `scrlayer-scrplain` pagestlye `headings` is an alias for `scrheadings` and `plain` is an alias for `plain.scrheadings`.

Twosided document: `\headmark` uses `\rightmark` for odd pages and `\leftmark` for even pages. Option `automark` is the same as `\automark[section]{chapter}`. Then the a new chapter sets a left mark and cleans the right mark. A new section sets a right mark.

Onesided document: There are only recto (odd) pages. `\headmark` uses `\rightmark`. Option `automark` is the same as `\automark{chapter}`. Then a new chapter sets the left and the right mark. The optional argument of `\automark` would be ignored until you are set `autooneside=false`.

To set the content in the center of the footer you can use:

- `\cfoot{<content for scrheadings>}`
- `\cfoot[<content for plain>]{<content for scrheadings>}`
- `\cfoot*{<content for both plain and scrheadings>}`
- `\cefoot{<content for scrheadings on even pages>}`
- `\cofoot{<content for scrheadings on odd pages>}`
- `\cefoot[...]{...}` and `\cofoot[...]{...}`
- `\cefoot*{...}` and `\cofoot*{...}`

Note that chapter pages usese page style `plain` by default. This can be changed by redefining `\chapterpagestyle`.

---

Regarding your example:

If the book title should be in the center of the footer on all odd pages including chapter pages use

```
\cofoot*{Book Title}
```

If the chapter should be in the center of the footer on even pages use

```
\cefoot{\headmark}% or \leftmark
```

If the section should be in the center of the footer on even pages use

```
\cefoot{\rightmark}
```

Example with chapters in the footer:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cofoot*{Book Title}
\cefoot{\headmark}% or \leftmark
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}
\author{Book Author}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\chapter{First chapter} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A section} 
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another} 
\lipsum[11-15] 
\end{document}
```

---

`\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` are called by `\chapter` and `\section` to set the left and right marks depending on option `automark` or command `\automark`. This can be disabled using `manualmark` or `\manualmark`.

If you use `\automark{section}` a new section sets both the left and the right mark while chapter does not set any mark.

So in the following example `\headmark` prints the section in the footer:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cofoot*{Book Title}
\cefoot{\headmark}% or \leftmark
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}
\author{Book Author}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\chapter{First chapter} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A section} 
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another} 
\lipsum[11-15] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Why and when `\clearpairofpagestyles`?

`scrlayer-scrpage` defines two new page styles `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. Together they build a pair of page styles similar to `headings` and `plain` in most classes. Both `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` are predefined with page numbers (`\pagemark`). `scrheadings` is also predefined with running head elements (`\headmark`). Where these are placed depend on the `pagestyleset` and whether `oneside` or `twoside` layout. The default of `pagestyleset` depends on whether or not using a KOMA-Script class. See the manual for more information about `pagestyleset` and defaults for the the page styles.

If you only want to move, e.g., the page number from, e.g., the *outer foot* element of a twosided `scrbook` document, to the *centre foot* element, you could use

```
\ofoot*{}% or \ofoot[]{}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% or \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

The first line defines the *outer foot* element to be empty of both `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. The second line defines the *centre foot* element of both `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` to be `\pagemark`, the page number element. If you omit the first line, you will nevertheless get a page number in the *centre foot* element, but the page number in the *outer foot* element will still be there.

If you want to define `scrheadings` from scratch, you can first clean it up defining all the elements empty using `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles`. This is defined as `\ihead{}\chead{}\ohead{}\ifoot{}\cfoot{}\ofoot{}`.

If you want to define `plain.scrheadings` from scratch, you can clean it up defining all the elements empty using `\clearplainofpairofpagestyles`. This command cannot be replaced by `\ihead` etc. because `\ihead` cannot be used to redefine the `plain` page style without the main page style.

If you want to define `plain.scrheadings` and `scrheadings` from scratch use `\clearpairofpagestyles`. It is the same like `\ihead[]{}\chead[]{}\ohead[]{}\ifoot[]{}\cfoot[]{}\ofoot[]{}`.

The names `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles`, `\clearplainofpairofpagestyles`, `\clearpairofpagestyles` are somehow general instead of specific for `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`, because `scrlayer-scrpage` can be used to define additional pairs. In this case the commands are related to the current pair instead of the pair `scrheadings` + `plain.scrheadings`. `scrheadings` + `plain.scrheadings` is the default pair only.

### What is `\ifoot`, `\cfoot`, `\ofoot`?

`\ifoot[foo]{bar}` is a shortcut of `\refoot[foo]{bar}\lofoot[foo]{bar}`.
`\ifoot` means *inner foot* elements. `\refoot` means *right foot* element of *even* pages. `\lofoot` means *left foot* element of *odd* pages. Only twoside documents distinguish even and odd pages. With oneside documents you have only odd pages.

`\cfoot[foo]{bar}` is a shortcut of `\cefoot[foo]{bar}\cofoot[foo]{bar}`. It defines the centre foot element of both even and odd pages. So if you want to distinguish the centre foot elements of odd and even pages, you can use `\cefoot` and `\cofoot`.

`\ofoot[foo]{bar}` is a shortcut of `\lefoot[foo]{bar}\rofoot[foo]{bar}`.

There is a picture in the KOMA-Script manual to visualize the meaning of these commands:

[image: from scrguien]

### What is `\headmark`?

`\headmark` is `\rightmark` on odd pages and `\leftmark` on even pages. There's not magic. It makes it easier to place the running head, e.g, in the outer margin, because you can simply use `\ohead{\headmark}` instead of `\lehead{\leftmark}\rohead{\rightmark}`.

LaTeX handles running heads by a pair of marks. The low level commands to set them are `\markboth{left mark}{right mark}` and `\markright{right mark}`. `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are used to get these marks. Usually book and report classes use `\chaptermark{…}` and `\sectionmark{…}` to set these marks automatically for the `headings` page style inside the headings commands `\chapter` and `\section`. `scrlayer-scrpage` extends this, e.g, by a command `\markleft` and by `\automark`. `\automark` is used to redefine `\partmark`, `\chaptermark`, `\sectionmark` etc. to add automatic running heads to the given levels. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\automark` and the other commands.

Currently there is nothing like `\titlemark{…}` and also no `title` element for `\automark`. So the title cannot be used as automatic running head element. You have to set it as a static or manual element. In your example, you've tried to use a static element and I will do so in the final section too.

### Final

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% pagemark at outer foot element of plain.scrheadings and scrheadings 
\cefoot{Book Title}% book title at centre foot element of scrheadings on even pages
\cofoot{\headmark}% head mark at centre foot element of scrheadings on odd pages
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\chapter{First chapter} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{A section} 
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-20] 
\section{Another} 
\lipsum[11-15] 
\end{document}
```

Will produce:

[image]

But on the first page of a chapter page style `plain.scrheadings` is used and therefore the *centre foot* element will be empty. If you want the chapter their too, you have to replace

```
\cofoot{\headmark}
```

by

```
\cofoot*{\headmark}
```

or the equal

```
\cofoot[\headmark]{\headmark}
```

This will add the mark to the plain page style `plain.scrheadings` too. If you don't want the mark on all plain pages but on the chapter page, you can instead use

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}
```

to tell `scrreprt` that is has to use the `headings` page style instead of the `plain` page style for the chapter pages. Note: If you use `scrlayer-scrpage` the `headings` page style is the main page style of the current pair of page styles. By default this is `scrheadings`.

Instead of `\headmark` you can use `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` at the example above, because I've used `\automark[chapter]{chapter}` to make both the chapter title.